# Web pages in JSON

Tags: html, json, standards

It is known that json format is clearer and way less verbose than xml.

Why wouldn't browsers and servers agree to send/display pages in json instead of html ? Wouldn't it be a gain in bandwith ? Am I mistaken ? Has this question ever been asked by consortiums ?

Why not change

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">Stuff</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

into a kind of jsonml

```
{
    html:
    {
        body: 
        {
             div: {id:'container', text:'Stuff'}
        }
    }
}
```

Verbosity may not be obvious in this example actually... But clarity is.

Comment: What if you want to put a div, two spans and a link within another div ?

Comment: Besides having to change the entire web and all the web browsers?

Comment: @YellowBird there would be keywords just as in html for subelements, to differentiate attributes and contents

Comment: There is a library for the same idea as yours! Let me search for it...

Comment: JSON was only invented around 2001, by which time browsers had already been written that parsed and displayed HTML. HTML is based on SGML-type languages, which have been around a lot longer--since the mid-80s or so.

Comment: @codebox even though changing everything would be an enormous change, does it make my question not worth being asked ?

Comment: Well, changing something that works, by something "new" that implies a king-kong new work, do you really think it worth it ?

Comment: @YellowBird Browsers could actually be made capable of displaying a web page from a different language, without breaking html compatibility. I don't think such a change could be made in an exclusive way.

Comment: @SimonBudin One advantage with HTML is that using tag delimiters that are not commonly used in standard text makes it relatively easy for humans to hand-create HTML. Can you imagine the capacity for error there would be if humans were hand-writing JSON?! People manage to mangle HTML in all sorts of creative, horrendous ways as it is; I dread to think what they could do with JSON.